# Is it possible to enable JavaScript source maps in Safari 6?

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, minify, source-maps

I am working with some minified JavaScript code and really benefit from having source maps for debugging. In Chrome, I had no problem enabling source maps and they are currently working for me.

I'm currently forced to use the Safari dev tools to do some work on this, and I can't for the life of me figure out to enable source maps in Safari. I have had no luck Googling for it.

Has anybody had any success enabling source maps for JavaScript in the Safari? I am using the latest version 6.0.4.

Comment: Source Maps were added into Safari 6.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that you can't do this as of Safari 6.0.4.

However a solution that is working for me instead is to use the [Webkit Nightlies](http://nightly.webkit.org/). I've been enjoying the debug tools in there so far, and it does support source maps.